# How to open json file dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a json file within a folder that I want to open dynamically within my main `app.py`, is there a way to do this?

This is what my folders look like

```
C:.
|   app.py
|   README.txt
|   tree.txt
|
+---resources
|       stores.json
|
+---templates
|       Tails.html
|
+---test
|       Unit_Test.py
|
\---__pycache__
        app.cpython-37.pyc
        Tails.cpython-37.pyc
```

I currently have this is app.py which gives me an error; `expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType`

```
from pydoc import locate

def read_jsonfile():
    with open(locate('resources.stores.json')) as f:
        stpres = json.load(f)

    return stores
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: forgot the `f`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import json

def read_jsonfile():
    with open('resources/stores.json') as f:
        stores = json.load(f)

    return stores
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `stores.json` has fixed path relative to C drive you in you `getJSON` function you can `change working dir` to that path like:

Since I am using linux as assuming my file is at `/home/user/resource/store.json` and I am working from some other file path:

```
import os

def getJSON():
    curr = os.getcwd()
    csvFilePath = os.chdir("/home/user/resource")
    with open("store.json") as f:
        print("do something")
    os.chdir(curr)
```

See if this helps.